# Is docker an ephemeral instance?

Tags: docker

I created a few docker images, i did wget and apt-get install on one.

Everytime I exit the docker instance, after going back to the image again, e.g. ubuntu:myimage it seems to spawn a new fresh version of it so that means all my apt-get install and wget are "lost".

I realized it's not persistent so i did docker commit... is this a proper way to have "persistence" in docker?

My question: is it possible to have persistence without doing commit all the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `docker run` command will start a new container from the provided image. Use `docker start` to restart a previously stopped container.

If you want to save changes back to the image, it is possible to use the `docker commit` command, but this is almost definitely not what you want. Instead, use a Dockerfile to build images and update it whenever you want to make a change. This way you can easily recreate the image and make changes without starting from scratch. For persistence (.e.g. config files and databases) use volumes, which are just directories stored outside of the Union File System as normal directories on the host.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `docker run image`, because it will create a new container from the image.

You can use `docker start container` to start your container, or run `docker attach` to attach a running container.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker ps -a 

docker commit ID yourname:tag

docker run -itd --name con yourname:tag
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to build a reusable image**, you most probably want to write  a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/): a step-by-step description of the modifications you want to make to a base image.

If instead you just want to shutdown and resume your container **like if it was a Vagrant virtual machine**, use

`docker run --name $container_name $image_name`

and then

`docker [start|stop] $container_name`

Note that the Docker system expects you to explicitly declare a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) if you need a persisten filesystem.